# ObservableCollection binding on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have Observable collection with MarketPrices , This observable collection I have bind to an ItemsControl as Below .

1) Now I don't want to show all Items in Observable Collection , want to show only items that user click Add  and selected Pair (GBPJPY, USDGBP..) needs to show in Items Control.

2) If user changed item in Comobobox from GBPJPY to USDGBP , then the price( DataTemplate) of GBPJPY need to update USDGBP.

How can I achieve both conditions. Please note that below code doesn't have real-time update but in project I have relatime price update as well, so observable collection updates on price changes.

[image]
**Code So Far**

```
 public class PriceModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _askPrice;
        private double _offerPrice;
        private string _selectedPair;

        public PriceModel()
        {
            Pairs = new ObservableCollection<string> {"GBPUSD", "GBPEUR", "USDGBP", "GBPJPY"};
        }

        public double AskPrice
        {
            get { return _askPrice; }
            set
            {
                _askPrice = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AskPrice");
            }
        }

        public double OfferPrice
        {
            get { return _offerPrice; }
            set
            {
                _offerPrice = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OfferPrice");
            }
        }

        public string SelectedPair
        {
            get { return _selectedPair; }
            set
            {
                _selectedPair = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(SelectedPair);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Pairs { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }



   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            MarketPrices = new ObservableCollection<PriceModel>
            {
                new PriceModel {AskPrice = 1.60345, OfferPrice = 1.60335, SelectedPair = "GBPUSD"},
                new PriceModel {AskPrice = 1.71345, OfferPrice = 1.71335, SelectedPair = "GBPEUR"},
                new PriceModel {AskPrice = 1.23345, OfferPrice = 1.23335, SelectedPair = "USDGBP"},
                new PriceModel {AskPrice = 1.34345, OfferPrice = 1.34335, SelectedPair = "GBPJPY"}
            };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<PriceModel> MarketPrices { get; set; } 
    }
```

**XAML**

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MarketPrices}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="5" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel AllowDrop="True" ClipToBounds="True">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Pairs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPair}" />
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="Ask Price" />
                                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding AskPrice}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="Offer Price" />
                                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding OfferPrice}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Use a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx). You might also want to read [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CollectionViewSourceIsCrazyUsefulForBindingToFilteredObservableCollectionsOnWindowsPhone8.aspx) or [here](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html)... (or Google for it...)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display a list of pairs in a ComboBox and the details for a Selected pair only but not for all pairs?

If that's the case, there are couple problems with the code.

**PriceModel**

You do not need a collection of all available pairs in your PriceModel class. Also, You do not need SelectedPair property in this class, may be your intention was to indicate the name of the pair, you could update your PriceModel to:

```
public class PriceModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _askPrice;
    private double _offerPrice;
    private string _pair;

    public PriceModel(string pair)
    {
        _pair = pair;
    }

    public string Pair
    {
        get { return _pair; }
    }

    public double AskPrice
    {
        get { return _askPrice; }
        set
        {
            _askPrice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AskPrice");
        }
    }

    public double OfferPrice
    {
        get { return _offerPrice; }
        set
        {
            _offerPrice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OfferPrice");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

You have a property named `MarketPrices` to hold the collection of Pairs, but no property to hold the Selected pair. Add a property named `SelectedPair` of type `PriceModel`. The Updated code would like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PriceModel _selectedPair;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        MarketPrices = new ObservableCollection<PriceModel>
        {
            new PriceModel("GBPUSD") {AskPrice = 1.60345, OfferPrice = 1.60335, },
            new PriceModel("GBPEUR") {AskPrice = 1.71345, OfferPrice = 1.71335, },
            new PriceModel("USDGBP") {AskPrice = 1.23345, OfferPrice = 1.23335, },
            new PriceModel("GBPJPY") {AskPrice = 1.34345, OfferPrice = 1.34335, }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PriceModel> MarketPrices { get; set; }

    public PriceModel SelectedPair
    {
        get { return _selectedPair; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPair = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPair");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

You could just use ComboBox to display the list of available pairs and update your bindings for TextBoxes to refer SelectedPair.

Update XAML would look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Pairs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPair}" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="Ask Price" />
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding SelectedPair.AskPrice}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="Offer Price" />
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding SelectedPair.OfferPrice}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Sample Output**

[image]